# Multiplication of two raster stack with R using multicore parallel processes

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, error, parallel-processing

I am working with two global raster stacks, each containing 60 layers using the R Software. The layers are global raster files (in GTiff format) at a resolution of 5 min of arc. The first stack contains cultivated areas for 60 crops, while the second stack contains the grid-cell yield of the same 60 crops.

my objective is to multiply the two raster stacks, in order to obtain the production for the 60 crops for each grid-cell. I am running this calculation using the `raster` package and using its parallelizing function `clusterR` together with the fuction `calc`. I am running the process using 24 cores. The code looks like this:

```
rasters_production <- clusterR(rasters_land_use_hectars, calc, args=list(fun=function(x){x*rasters_yield}),
                        export="rasters_yield", exclude="parallel", filename=paste0("Script_generated_files/", "organic_rasters_production_1.tif"), format="GTiff", overwrite=T, cl=cluster)
```

When I run it, the code generate the following error:

```
Error in clusterR(rasters_land_use_hectars, calc, args = list(fun = function(x) { : cluster error
```

Nevertheless, if I run the same multiplication but multiplying a raster stack for a vector of 60 coefficient (and not for a second raster stack), the calculation works correctly?

Does somebody know why the calculation between the two raster stacks does not work instead?

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the documentation for ClusterR you'll see you need a couple extra lines of code, like:

```
beginCluster(cpus = n)
x <- clusterR(stuff)
endCluster()
```

you may also need `forceapply = TRUE` in your calc function, unless I'm misreading what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. Nevertheless, also including `forceapply = TRUE` the code does not work. To my understanding, I think there should be a problem with the master branch when coming to summaring the results of the different chunks. Any idea about any reason why that might happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `mclapply` in `parallel` package, where `NUM_CORES` is the total number of cores you wanna use.

```
 rasters_production <- stack(mclapply(1:nlayers(rasters_yield)), function(i){ 
        rasters_land_use_hectars[[i]] * rasters_yield[[i]]
    }, mc.cores = NUM_CORES))
```